# How to config PORT KNOCKING on CSF ubuntu server and access it by linux?

Tags: server, security, firewall, vps

I'm trying to run port knocking work on a CSF on a small VPS, i setup this:

1 - the result of csf first test ok

2 -

```
TCP_IN = "53,80"
TCP_OUT = "53,80,113,443"
UDP_IN = "53"
UDP_OUT = "53,113,123"
PORTKNOCKING = "3000;TCP;30;1000;1001;1002;1003" //dummy ports
```

3 - after `csf -r`

4 - after restarted the vps

5 - tryed to use knockd on pc to knock the server

```
knock -v 0.0.0.0 1000 1001 1002 1003 //dummy ip
```

6 - and less than 20 seconds use

```
ssh myuser@0.0.0.0 -p 3000 //dummy ip
```

but cant connect, i never did it before, like a printf("HelloWorld"); for me. If someone could help me i will be really glad.

More info, my sshd_config:

PORT 3000
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
AllowUsers myuser